# Cursor query from specific image folder, not load all image from sdcard

Tags: android, cursor

The code below will return all image from the `SD card`. But, I need to modify it so that it only display images from other folders.

```
Uri mImageUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;   
ContentResolver mContentResolver = mContext.getContentResolver();

Cursor mCursor = mContentResolver.query(mImageUri, null, null, null, null);
```

I have tried this:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Testing/";

Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);

Cursor mCursor = mContentResolver.query(Uri, null, null, null, null);
```

and am getting an error. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Uri mImageUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

// field data which u need
final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED};


Cursor mCursor = mContentResolver.query(mImageUri, columns, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " like ? ",new String[] {"%/YourFolderName/%"}, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> fileNames  =null
File path = 
File(getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).path,
  "Your Folder Name")

 if (path.exists()) {
     fileNames = path.getList() //you may need to to adjust the Data type of fileNames
}
```

So, now you have list of images path that you can pass on to recycler view using recycler view Adapter.